# Missing binaries hv_get_dhcp_info and hv_get_dns_info

Tags: debian, hyper-v

I have a Debian 11 system fairly recently installed and I see a lot of these messages in the log:

```
hv_kvp_daemon[1312301]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dns_info: not found
hv_kvp_daemon[1312303]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dhcp_info: not found
```

In another forum it was suggested to fix this by making soft links from /usr/sbin to those locations but I do not have those binaries in /usr/sbin either - my /usr/sbin just has these:

```
ls /usr/sbin/hv*
/usr/sbin/hv_fcopy_daemon  /usr/sbin/hv_kvp_daemon  /usr/sbin/hv_vss_daemon
```

Any idea what package needs to be installed to get these files?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer eventually - these are just shell scripts and can be found on github here:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/hv